Avoiding division by zero in deconvolution
I have a signal that was filtered in the time domain with a moving triangle window (convolved with the triangle function) and I need to recover the (approximate) original signal after convolution. The process is described by:
$
\langle q_{\text{convolved}}(t) \rangle = \langle q_{\text{true}}(t) \rangle * \Delta(t)
$
In the Fourier domain:
$
\hat{q}_{\text{convolved}}(f) = \hat{q}_{\text{true}}(f) \cdot \text{sinc}^2(f)
$.
To retrieve $ \hat{q}_{\text{true}}(f) $, I must divide by $ \text{sinc}^2(f) $, but this function is zero at certain points, leading to division by zero.
What are effective numerical methods to handle or avoid division by zero (or very small values) in this context? Any suggestions for regularization or alternative methods?

There are several non-Fourier methods the description of which you can easily find online (most of them deal with the Gaussian convolution, but the triangle one should be only easier), and there might be a good way to regularize as well, but I don't want to recommend anything particular before I try it myself. So what is your signal duration, what is the width of the sliding window, how large is the noise in the output compared to the signal itself, and what type of the original signal do you expect: (smooth, discrete spikes, on-off (union of characteristic functions of intervals), etc.)?

Also what is the sampling frequency (I suspect that you actually have the discrete data at a certain step)?

@fedja
Thanks for the explanations. The primary modulation frequency is 0.01 Hz superimposed with a stochastic signal on top of it (from a turbulent flow). The amplitude of the stochastic process is about 10 percent of the amplitude of the primary modulation. I have 10000 equidistant sample points per period and a total signal is about 30 periods long (30*100 seconds). The width of the triangle windows is 200 sample points. The original signal  would be a smooth function (a sine function with frequency of 0.01 plus higher frequency modulations of about 10 percent of its amplitude)

Just to make one thing clear: is the stochastic signal superimposed with the original one before or after the convolution? (I would guess "before", but it is easier to ask) :-)

Of course it is superimpose before :)

And it is just the iid Gaussian at each measurement, as usual?

unfortunately, it is not and this is one thing that needs to be investigated afterwards. But for the sake of simplicity for this example, we can assume IID Gaussian

Yeah, if there is a smooth bias in the noise, I have no idea how it can be possibly distinguished from a component of the original signal... OK, give me some time to experiment. What is your precision goal for the recovery?

well, it should asymptotically converge to the original signal if the signal becomes longer and longer (except the high-frequency content that is lost because of the convolution)

Yeah, but I mean for this particular setup of 30 periods, what is the relative error you'll be happy with?

anything below 5 percent would be great, 5 to 10 percent acceptable

${1\over x}\sim{x \over x^2+\epsilon^2}$

@user619894 thanks but, this really doesn't solve the issue, numerically division by a small value like ϵ2, shoots up the error when x is small

you cannot regularize division by zero, you can only regularize a cancelation, eg $x/x$

We can recover much of the original signal by studding the second derivative:
$q_{\text{conv}}''(t) = 2;q_{\text{true}}(t) - (q_{\text{true}}(t+1) + q_{\text{true}}(t-1))$
